# MATLAB: Combine all videos in directory

Tags: matlab, video, concatenation, avi

I have directories that each have several short (~10 second) `.avi` videos. Does anybody know how I can concatenate all of the videos in a specific directory in alphabetical order to form one single video?

I would try to use VLC, but I have to do this for over a thousand different directories. I didn't realize this would be so difficult, but not able to find anything on Google.

**More specifics:**
For each directory I want to perform this action on, all videos are guaranteed to be:
`.avi`,`MJPG`,`20fps`,`640x480 resolution`,`no audio`,`between less than 1 second to 15 seconds long`
I'd like the single video file to play just as if I played the individuals back-to-back. 
If there's any other specifics I missed please let me know.

The combined videos are intended to all be put into the same directory and given to another person to perform their own video processing on with Matlab. They'll be doing something with either crosscorrelation or machine learning to try and identify a particular object in the videos.

Comment: Do you understand the hidden complexity? **What happens with: different video-codec, different video-framerate, different audio-codec, different audio-sample-rate, different resolution, different number of color-channels**? It's not a problem of tools (ffmpeg beeing the most powerful) but a problem of problem-definition. (to be more clear: avi is a container; it does not guarantee anything about the stuff i mentioned above)

Comment: Hmm I know very little about video so I did not realize all that. However, the videos are guaranteed to all be .avi, MJPG, 20fps, 640x480 resolution, and no audio, if that simplifies things.

Comment: Then start with [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#samecodec). (There is at least one more decision: re-compression: easy -> you can basically read in all videos in your order and encode a new one; or just concatenation while keeping the actual compressed-stuff: less easy as this is highly dependent on multiplexing giving some codec)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the implication of that, does that mean the combined video size will be larger than the sum of the individual sizes?

Comment: This is a very broad question and can't be answered in general. You may see it as: i got file A and file B, just let some player play fileA, then fileB. But that's not a valid media-file in general. Therefore it's much more complex (although some playlist-like approach within a matroska-container might be enough; we don't know your use-case). Also: a recompression-approach (with some lossy codec) will always lose quality.

Comment: Thanks, is there any particular information I could add that would make my situation less general?

Comment: Just describe your use-case more specifically. And be sure to check out some basics of media-compression. These problems apply to audio and images as well. Combining 2 jpegs (left & right) without recompression/loss is not easy and when one of those is of some pixel-size-dimension not compatible with macroblock-size one might be in big trouble!

Comment: **Ok, final remarks:** (1) If you still want to combine these, your chances got better as it all sounds quite constant (parameter-wise) & mjpg is an intra-only format (no complex intra-frame stuff which could be a problem, not sure). So ffmpeg, as described in my comment will help. (2) **But much more important:** it's imho the wrong way to go. Just pass those short clips and your assumption on the order / extra ordering-textfile. If this guy is doing ML on video, he will be able to concatenate video-frames too (when order is defined). Less chances to do mistakes (e.g. losing quality)

Comment: My last comment is based on the fact, that in ML, everything is based on basic RGB-like 2d-arrays (uncompressed images in memory; ignoring some more complex stuff like IR-channels). If someone is able to read video into some multi-dim array / tensor for ML; he can do that for multiple videos too.

Comment: that sounds very reasonable, but I was basically told I have to combine them to save them time.

Comment: That just means that there is a lack of knowledge or some communication problem. I'm not sure what kind of ML-stuff is going on. But the short-clip approach also has advantages: given 3 channels, 20fps and 640x480, 1 minute approximately needs 1GB of memory. So if you got your thousands of directories with these clips it's quite possible, that he even would not be able to read this video into his memory to do ML-calcs (maybe even a 128gb memory machine will not be enough). He probably needs to do this partially and in this case a natural clipwise approach might shine(esp. for complex codecs).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. each combined video would actually end up being only about 1 minute or less because the individual videos tend to be very short (1-2s for most). I'll definitely take all that into consideration though. The ffmpeg page you linked seems to work well in my initial test too in case I need that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of the `VideoReader` and `VideoWriter` (see [doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/convert-between-image-sequences-and-video.html) for more examples). Iterate through your video files in alphabetical order and "stream" them into a new file.

I threw together some (untested) code. I have no idea how fast this is, though:

```
cd(VIDEO_DIRECTORY);
tmp = dir('*.avi');        % all .avi video clips
videoList = {tmp.name}';   % sort this list if necessary! sort(videoList) might work

% create output in seperate folder (to avoid accidentally using it as input)
mkdir('output');
outputVideo = VideoWriter(fullfile(workingDir,'output/mergedVideo.avi'));
% if all clips are from the same source/have the same specifications
% just initialize with the settings of the first video in videoList
inputVideo_init = VideoReader(videoList{1}); % first video
outputVideo.FrameRate = inputVideo_init.FrameRate;

open(outputVideo) % >> open stream
% iterate over all videos you want to merge (e.g. in videoList)
for i = 1:length(videoList)
    % select i-th clip (assumes they are in order in this list!)
    inputVideo = VideoReader(videoList{i});
    % -- stream your inputVideo into an outputVideo
    while hasFrame(inputVideo)
        writeVideo(outputVideo, readFrame(inputVideo));
    end
end
close(outputVideo) % << close after having iterated through all videos
```

Comment: Crazy slow but works a treat. This saved me the time of figuring out how to do it with ffmpeg. Tested on 3, 20 second MP4 files (outputted as MP4 as well) and it took over a minute.